# Detection of simcard on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, sim-card

I want to add an security feature for that I need to check if sim [contactno], installed on perticular device [android/ios].

ex:  i need to check if no like 989xxxx640 is available in device or not.

Comment: on iOS you cannot obtain the subscriber number.  It is a privacy issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [CTCarrier carrierName]:

If you configure a device for a carrier and then remove the SIM card, this property retains the name of the carrier.

As far as I know, you cannot detect if the SIM card is installed. You can only determine if a WWAN connection is available using Reachability.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int checkSim(){    
    TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
        switch (simState) {
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                return SIM_PRESENT;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
            default :
                return SIM_ABSENT;
        }
}
```

use this code for sim check

Comment: this will check if sim is present or not but i need to check if no like 989xxxx640 is available in device or not.